# Window topbar title positioning

Tags: themes, titlebar

I installed Numix GTK theme and everything is fine, but one thing that catches my eye:
Title is not centered, because of close/minimize buttons, I guess. How can I adjust it? I didn't find any similar rule in .css. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think that depends on your window manager theme, whatever that is and not on the gtk theme, in this case Numix.

Comment: You mean, Unity? The "Unity" folder contains only titlebar images.